# Comparing two seemingly identical variables does not trigger if statement BATCH-file

Tags: git, batch-file

I'm writing a simple scrip to check if my git branch is up to date, but when I try to compare the output from git status with my predefined string the if statement never trigger even though echo %%i and displays the exact same string I'm comparing against.

```
   SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

   echo off
   D:
   cd D:\GitHub\goworkspace\src\Programvareutvikling
   set cmd="git status -uno"
   set msg=Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/Server'.
   FOR /F "tokens=*" %%i IN (' %cmd% ')  DO ( 
   REM this line never triger even when it seems like it should
   set X=%%i
   IF  !X! == %msg% Echo uptodate
   )

   pause
```

Any help would be appreciated; this is my first question on stack exchange so please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong. Alternate solutions is also appreciated, but I'd prefer not having to install additional programs.

This is the output:

```
echo %msg% >Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/Server'.
echo !X!  >Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/Server'.
echo %msg% >Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/Server'.
echo !X!  >nothing to commit (use -u to show untracked files)
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Solution: I was not using quotes around the variables.

```
    IF /I "%%~i"=="%msg%" Echo uptodate
```

Comment: I would remove the quotes from this line: `set cmd="git status -uno"`

Comment: Did that and the program ran just like it did before, the output is still exactly the same, but the if statement still does not trigger

Comment: You need to put quotes in your comparison because there are spaces in your string and I would just use the FOR variable isntead. `IF  /I "%%~i"=="%msg%" Echo uptodate`.

Comment: Your code should have thrown an error on your screen because you were not using quotes in your comparison. `[string] was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Thank you so much, I tried similar solutions as you pointed out earlier, that is why i ended up with the X variable, it seems like what i was doing wrong was not having the quotes, what are the use of /I and ~ ? but anyway this solved my problem thank you :)

Comment: It did not throw an error even with echo on, so I couldn't figure out what was wrong

Comment: Read the help for the `IF` command to figure out what the `/I` option does. And read the help for the `FOR` command to understand what the `~` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need to `EnableDelayedExpansion`, use a `For` loop or even make an `If` comparison.

Would this not achieve your goal?

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "D:\GitHub\goworkspace\src\Programvareutvikling"
Set "cmd=git status -uno"
Set "msg=branch is up-to-date"
%cmd%|Find "%msg%">Nul&&(Echo up to date)||Echo needs updating
Pause
```

You can optionally include the case insensitive, **`/I`**, option with `Find` too.